# What does 'turn to' mean in the end of the sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning

What does 'turn to' mean in the end of sentence?

> She had lost the protection of Calvin's hand. Charles was nowhere, either **to save or to turn to**. She was alone in a fragment of nothingness.

*A Wrinkle in Time* by Madeleine L'Engle

Answer (score 1):

***[Turn to:](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/turn-to)***

> [T] [turn to someone] to go to someone for help when you are having difficulty dealing with a situation.

(MacMillan Dictionary))

Answer (score 1):

'Turn to' can have several different meanings.

- To turn to (drugs/alcoholism): You start taking drugs or become an alcoholic. "He has turned to drugs to cope with his depression"
- Turn to (+ verb): Physically turning your body. "I turned to see my sister standing there"
- Turn to: Changing an idea or moral. "He has turned to see religion in a different way".

But the meaning the applies to your sentence is:

- Turn to (at the end of a sentence): something that you end up doing to get help. "I think you should speak to your mother. She is a good person to turn to".